# Count elements that have the same value for a specific property and put the result in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce), I am trying to count the elements that have the same value for a specific property. I want to put the result in an array  of objects containing a property for the value of the grouped by property and another one for the count. How can I do this easily in javascript ?

```js
const CATEGORY = {
  STRATEGY: 'STRATEGY',
  CONTENT: 'CONTENT',
  ADVERTISING: 'ADVERTISING',
  MEASURMENT: 'MEASURMENT'
}

const lessons = [
  {
    title: 'ohoho',
    category: CATEGORY.STRATEGY
  }, {
    title: 'hihihi',
    category: CATEGORY.CONTENT
  }, {
    title: 'hello',
    category: CATEGORY.CONTENT
  }
]

let categoryLessonCount = lessons.reduce(function (acc, lesson) {
  acc[lesson.category] ? acc[lesson.category]++ : acc[lesson.category] = 1
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(categoryLessonCount[CATEGORY.STRATEGY])
console.log(categoryLessonCount[CATEGORY.CONTENT])
```

Actual categoryLessonCount value :

```
Object
{
  STRATEGY: 1, 
  CONTENT: 2
}
```

Wanted categoryLessonCount value :

```
Array
[ 
  {
   title: 'STRATEGY', 
   count: 1
  }, {
   title: 'CONTENT', 
   count: 2
  } 
]
```

Comment: shouldn't `lessons` be an array? tried to edit it, but minimum of changes are 6 characters, so i couldn't save the edit.

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: *Actual categoryLessonCount* is `Object {STRATEGY: 1, CONTENT: 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the what you want just transform it into an array

```js
const CATEGORY = {
  STRATEGY: 'STRATEGY',
  CONTENT: 'CONTENT',
  ADVERTISING: 'ADVERTISING',
  MEASURMENT: 'MEASURMENT'
}

const lessons = [{
  title: 'ohoho',
  category: CATEGORY.STRATEGY
}, {
  title: 'hihihi',
  category: CATEGORY.CONTENT
}, {
  title: 'hello',
  category: CATEGORY.CONTENT
}]

let count = lessons.reduce(function(acc, lesson) {
  acc[lesson.category] ? acc[lesson.category] ++ : acc[lesson.category] = 1
  return acc
}, {})

// transform count into what you want
let categoryLessonCount = [];
for (let cat in count) {
  categoryLessonCount.push({
    'title': cat,
    'count': count[cat]
  });
}

console.log(categoryLessonCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
let categoryLessonCount = lessons.reduce(function(acc, lesson) {
  let found = false
  for (const item of acc) {
    if (item.title === lesson.category) {
      item.count++
      found = true
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    acc.push({
      title: lesson.category,
      count: 1
    })
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```

Your main issue is that your accumulating an object but expecting an array (note the final argument to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

Comment: works but less efficient then the first answer. thanks

Comment: @AlexB Sure, is it less efficient though? Not sure mine is optimal, but it does it in one step. Why do reduce and then loop again?

Comment: Yes because it loops on each element to find it's corresponding index in the group by array.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it depends on the data which way would be faster

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map` functions:

```
...
let categoryLessonCount = lessons.reduce(function (acc, lesson) {
  acc[lesson.category] ? acc[lesson.category]++ : acc[lesson.category] = 1
  return acc
}, {})

let counts = Object.keys(categoryLessonCount).map(
  (k) => ({title: k, count: categoryLessonCount[k]})
)

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the short solution but the strategy is the same as the accepted answer. 1up